# swift updating dictionary containing array

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
var headToHead: [Int: [Int]] = [
1:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
2:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
3:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
4:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
5:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
30:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
31:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
32:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

How do I update the elements in the array that is contained as the value of the dictionary items?

Comment: What does "update the elements in the array" even mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the 'subscript' accessors defined for Dictionary and for Array.  Like such

```
var da : [Int : [Int]] = [0:[0,0,0], 1:[1,1,1]]
da[0]![0]=10
da               // is [0:[10,0,0], 1:[1,1,1]]
```

Of course, exercise caution when unwrapping optionals; the above is simply an example.